# Efficiently extract lines containing a string in Python

Tags: python-2.7

Sometimes I need to get only lines containing a certain string from a text file (e.g., while parsing a logfile). I usually do it this way:

```python
with open(TEXTFILENAME,'r') as f:
  contents = f.readlines()

targets = [s for s in contents if FINDSTRING in s]
```

However, I saw there's a possible two-liner:

```
with open(TEXTFILENAME,'r') as f:
  targets = [s for s in f.readlines() if FINDSTRING in s]
```

I wonder if the second method is more efficient, whether the `readlines()` function in this case act as an iterator of sorts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid the call to `readlines`, which generates a list of all the lines. This should therefore be faster

```
with open(TEXTFILENAME,'r') as f:
    targets = [line for line in f if FINDSTRING in line]
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew I have overlooked something >.<